# Cloning element with jquery producing undesirable multiple copies

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my current project, I have this jquery function:

```
$(document).on("click", "button.multiple", function(){
    $(this).parent().first().find("input.multiple").after( $(this).parent().first().find("input.multiple").clone() );
});
```

which should, each time a button is clicked, add a new input element like this to the page:

```
<div>
    <label>Fotos</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control multiple" name="fotos" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default multiple">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>novo
    </button>
</div>
```

but when I click in the button, multiple copies of this element are produced. Anyone can tell what is wrong here?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle because it is not very clear what you are trying to do

Comment: `$(this).parent().first().find("input.multiple")` not returns only one elements if there is more, e.g, this will fix your issue: `$(this).parent().first().find("input.multiple").last().after( $(this).parent().first().find("input.multiple").first().clone() );`  But question is quite unclear then regarding expected behaviour...

Comment: @VDesign fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j9ez3jhc/

Comment: @A.Wolff fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j9ez3jhc/

Comment: @KleberMota put the `.first()` after the `.find()` both times : http://jsfiddle.net/j9ez3jhc/1/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon you suggestion worked, thanks. If you want, I will mark your answer as correct,if you post any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow sugestion from comments above, I solve this issue with this code:

```
$(document).on("click", "button.multiple", function(){
    $(this).parent().first().find("input.multiple").first().after(
        $(this).parent().first().find("input.multiple").first().clone()
    );
});
```